# KVM guest has a wrong outgoing ip address

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, debian-squeeze, bridge

I have a KVM host with a bridge configured on eth0 that has a public ip:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address xx.xx.aa.111
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network xx.xx.aa.0
  broadcast xx.xx.aa.255
  gateway xx.xx.aa.1
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp on
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
```

This host has a guest on it with its own public IP address:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address xx.xx.bb.246
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network xx.xx.bb.0
  broadcast xx.xx.bb.255
  gateway xx.xx.bb.1
```

However, when connecting from the guest with `xx.xx.bb.246` via ssh to another host, `auth.log` shows `xx.xx.aa.111` instead of `xx.xx.bb.246`. This troubles BIND9's zone transfers and notifies because other servers only allow connections from `xx.xx.bb.246` (the guest) and not from `xx.xx.aa.111` (the host), according to `syslog`.

`ip route show` of host:

```
xx.xx.aa.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src xx.xx.aa.111 
default via xx.xx.aa.1 dev br0
```

and for the guest:

```
xx.xx.bb.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src xx.xx.bb.246 
default via xx.xx.bb.1 dev eth0
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, stupid little thing that kept me busy for hours. There were two interfaces, one internal and one external on the guest. `traceroute` showed that outgoing connections were made through the internal network.